# Create Windows shortcut with "Run as administrator" option enabled

Tags: windows-10, uac

In Windows I can set up a shortcut to run application always as administrator:
[image]
[image]

I need to create such shortcut from the command line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8):

A [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29002207/1445609) shows how to accomplish this in Powershell. There's no easy interface to add the `Run as administrator` flag, so it involves flipping a bit in the `.LNK` binary file.

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$Home\Desktop\7-Zip File Manager.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe"
$Shortcut.Save()

$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$Home\Desktop\7-Zip File Manager.lnk")
$bytes[0x15] = $bytes[0x15] -bor 0x20 #set byte 21 (0x15) bit 6 (0x20) ON
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$Home\Desktop\7-Zip File Manager.lnk", $bytes)
```

Comment: Does this also work for non shortcut/lnk files?  (e.g.: EXE's)

Comment: @JuliusPIV , no, this only works for the LNK binary file.

Answer (score 0):

try with [shortcutJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat)  - it can create a shortcut with "run as admin" tick from command line :

```
call shortcutJS.bat -linkfile "some.lnk" -target "%cd%\some.bat" -adminpermissions yes
```

this also changes 21st byte of the file.
More information can be found [somewhere in this docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/16cb4ca1-9339-4d0c-a68d-bf1d6cc0f943?redirectedfrom=MSDN).